# DPLYR lookup or join? How to approach this?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two tables, both have the following fields:

- date
- id
- vegetables
- fruits
- metric

df2 is a subset of df1. df1 has ~8k records and df2 has about 4k.

My goal is to either create a new df or add a column to the parent data frame df1 with a true/false for whether or not the date/id combination exits in df2. A lookup basically.

Should I go the lookup table route or should I create a new data frame by joining df1 and 2?

I cannot join just on id, must be a combination of id and date since some ids return on different dates.

I tried `left_join()`

```
comb <- left_join(x = df1, y = df2, by=c("date", "id"))
```

But the result returned columns for fruits and vegetables for both when I really just wanted to retain df1 columns:

- date
- id
- vegetables.x
- fruits.x
- metric.x
- vegetables.y
- fruits.y
- metric.y

What I want is just:

- date
- id
- vegetables
- fruits
- InDF2 (boolean)
- metric

What is the best way to determine which rows (date + id) in df1 also exist in df2 (date + id)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Maybe `paste` the `date` and `id` into a vector for each `df`, say `df1_vector` and `df2_vector`
2. Use `%in%`
3. Try `df1$df2_presence_check = paste(df1$date,df1$id) %in% paste(df2$date,df2$id)`

**EXAMPLE**

```
set.seed(42)
a = sample(letters, 5)
b = sample(letters,15)
a %in% b
#[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE

#OR

b %in% a
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: That did the trick thank you for the suggestion, used this in combination with mutate() to add new column.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution entirely in `dplyr`. I'm assuming that id and date represents and unique key.

Let's add some data for reproduciblity

```
set.seed(23489)
n <- 10

df1 <- data.frame(
  id=sample(1e4:9e4, n),
  date=sample(seq(as.Date('2015/01/01'), as.Date('2017/01/01'), by="day"), n),
  vegetables= c("Broccoli", "Cabbage", "Calabrese", "Carrots", "Cauliflower", 
                "Celery", "Chard", "Endive", "Fiddleheads", "Frisee"),
  fruits=c("Jabuticaba", "Jackfruit", "Jambul", "Jujube", "Juniper berry",
           "Kiwi", "Kumquat", "Lemon", "Lime", "Loquat"),
  metric=rnorm(n=n)
)

df2 <- df1[sample(seq_len(nrow(df1)), n/2), ]
```

Next, we generate your desired output

```
df1 %>%
  left_join(select(mutate(df2, InDF2=TRUE), id, date, InDF2), by=c("id", "date")) %>%
  mutate(InDF2=ifelse(is.na(InDF2), FALSE, TRUE))

#       id       date  vegetables        fruits      metric InDF2
# 1  80283 2016-11-26    Broccoli    Jabuticaba  1.68765979 FALSE
# 2  14766 2016-10-18     Cabbage     Jackfruit -0.16774908 FALSE
# 3  19532 2015-03-29   Calabrese        Jambul -1.18328968  TRUE
# 4  46187 2015-03-09     Carrots        Jujube  1.83044569 FALSE
# 5  76852 2016-01-11 Cauliflower Juniper berry -0.05744373 FALSE
# 6  45507 2015-10-27      Celery          Kiwi -1.78166251 FALSE
# 7  65227 2016-07-07       Chard       Kumquat -1.84756162  TRUE
# 8  71433 2015-05-25      Endive         Lemon  0.77346596  TRUE
# 9  17002 2016-10-22 Fiddleheads          Lime  1.09118108  TRUE
# 10 52797 2015-06-29      Frisee        Loquat -0.46491328  TRUE
```